# Dynaconf: how to load a lot of different configs

Tags: python, configuration, config

I try to load all the config but `dynaconf` only see the data from the `settings.toml`

I have a project with the following structure

```
    .
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── settings.toml
│   │   └── settings_upd.toml
│   ├── config.py
│   └── main.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.in
```

Where `config` directory contains all the configs and `config.py` loads all the configs with the following code

```
from dynaconf import Dynaconf

settings = Dynaconf(
    envvar_prefix="DYNACONF",
    settings_files=[
        './my_project/config/settings_upd.toml',
        './my_project/config/settings.toml'
    ],
)
```

The `settings_upd.toml` is

```
[default]
last_name = "Your Last Name"
```

And the `settings.toml` is

```
[default]
name = "Your name"
```

So when I run the script with `poetry run python my_project/main.py`

```
from config import settings

print(settings.default)
```

I get

```
{'name': 'Your name'}
```

But I don't get any information from the first config.

So is it possible to load different configs and use them at once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `environments=True,`

In order for the environment support. You can refer to https://www.dynaconf.com/configuration/

```
`from dynaconf import Dynaconf

settings = Dynaconf(
envvar_prefix="MYPROGRAM",
settings_files=["settings.toml",".secrets.toml"],
environments=True,
load_dotenv=True,
env_switcher="MYPROGRAM_ENV",
**more_options
)`
```